# Error Code: 1055 incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench, mysql-error-1055

I have been having issues switching to an offline version of the Lahman SQL baseball database. I was using a terminal embed into an EDX course. This command runs fine on the web terminal:

```
SELECT concat(m.nameFirst,concat(" ",m.nameLast)) as Player,
    p.IPOuts/3 as IP,
    p.W,p.L,p.H,p.BB,p.ER,p.SV,p.SO as K,
    p.IPOuts+p.W*5+p.SV+p.SO-p.BB-p.L-p.H as PTS,
    p.yearID as Year
FROM Pitching p
Inner Join Master m
    ON p.playerID=m.playerID
WHERE p.yearID=2014 AND p.IPOuts>=50
GROUP BY m.playerID
ORDER BY PTS DESC;
```

Which is running SQL 5.5.46, but when I use my offline version running 5.7.10 I get the following error code:

> Error Code: 1055. Expression #1 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY 
>       clause and contains nonaggregated column 'stats.m.nameFirst' which is 
>       not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is 
>       incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by

I've been reading a lot of solutions to people's problems, but they haven't helped in this case. That's never happened before, so I think this is either super obvious or maybe I'm getting ok at coding. Anyway, anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: you don't need a `group by`.remove it.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/mysql/8245/error-1055-only-full-group-by-something-is-not-in-group-by-clause

Answer (score 76, accepted):

In 5.7 the sqlmode is set by default to:

```
 ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION
```

To remove the clause ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY you can do this:

```
SET sql_mode=(SELECT REPLACE(@@sql_mode,'ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY',''));
```

This supposed you need to make that GROUP BY with non aggregated columns.

Regards

Comment: You are right, and that does work. But it looks like I goofed and didn't need the group by clause at all. Thanks though, had I been doing it right this would have worked for me.

Comment: These changes of default from 5.5 to 5.6 are making life difficult for a lot of people. They are more than motivated, but generally not noticed. Regards

Comment: NOTE: changing the sql_mode will not affect stored procedures. So you need to drop and execute SP again to take affect

Answer (score 37):

The accepted solution above didn't work for me on version `5.7.9, for osx10.9 (x86_64)`.

Then the following worked -

```
set global sql_mode = 'STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION';
```

Comment: The accepted solution above didn't work for me on version 5.7.18  on Ubuntu  16.04 , but this works

Comment: Is there any permanent solution, resolve this instead of running this daily. anis?

Comment: @Kiran, yes. You've to add it in options file -  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/option-files.html

Comment: Yes! this solution is working on 5.7.35-0ubuntu0.18.04.1 - (Ubuntu). Thanks @Anis

Comment: @AbderrahimSoubai-Elidrisi maybe an accepted solution change your `sql_mode` to `,STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION`, or not set `sql_mode` in global

Answer (score 12):

For other use cases: You don't necessarily have to disable `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY`
Given a case like this, According to mysql docs, "This query is invalid if name is not a primary key of t or a unique NOT NULL column. In this case, no functional dependency can be inferred and an error occurs:"

```
SELECT name, address, MAX(age) FROM t GROUP BY name;
ERROR 1055 (42000): Expression #2 of SELECT list is not in GROUP
BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'mydb.t.address' which
is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this
is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by
```

Instead you can use this `ANY_VALUE('my_column_name') my_column_name` 
Quoting the mysql docs, "In this case, MySQL ignores the nondeterminism of address values within each name group and accepts the query."
Use ANY_VALUE() to refer to address:

```
SELECT name, ANY_VALUE(address), MAX(age) FROM t GROUP BY name;
```

Comment: Thank you!!! The same GROUP BY type of question can be found many times in this site, but the ANY_VALUE option is never mentioned... Perfect, thanks again!

Comment: Thank you sir!  Was searching for a minute on this one scratching my head.

Answer (score 9):

```
SET sql_mode=(SELECT REPLACE(@@sql_mode,'ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY',''));

** your query **
```

This will resolve your problem.

Comment: This worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

using mysql version 8.0.26. I tried a lot of solutions but nothing work. I changed Full groupBy mode change Engine_subsitution. at last, I tried this

```
mysql -u root -p -e "SET GLOBAL sql_mode = 'NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION';"
```

this worked for me

Answer (score 0):

If you do as the picked answer, the @sql_mode may be like this—

```
',STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION'.
```

there's a comma in front of the 'STRICT_TRANS_TABLES' string.

Just execute this—

```
set @@sql_mode = 
'STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION';
```

it works.

Also, you can try following exp,

```
SELECT REPLACE(@@sql_mode,'ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY,','');
```

I didn't test it, but I guess it may works.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is impossible to change *.cnf file in recent version.
Instead of, you can change mysql.service file

```
/lib/systemd/system/mysql.service
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/mysqld --sql-mode=STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION
```

It works well in recent version but it is not a best method
You can use following method

```
   SELECT name, max(address), MAX(age) FROM t GROUP BY name;
```

Answer (score 0):

Find mysql client.cnf file in (Linux)

- **/etc/my.cnf.d/client.cnf**

Then Add

```
[mysqld] 
sql_mode = ""
```

Then save and restart the MySQL service using

```
sudo systemctl restart mysqld
```

then check whether the MySQL service is running without error

```
sudo systemctl status mysqld
```

if this is running without error, it will fix your error.

Answer (score 0):

**There are several ways we can go about resolving this issue. Below are six options for dealing with this issue.**

Example of Error
First, here’s an example of code that produces the error:

SELECT
District,
Name,
SUM(Population) FROM City
WHERE CountryCode = 'AUS'
GROUP BY District;
Result:

ERROR 1055 (42000): Expression #2 of the SELECT list is not in the GROUP BY clause and c

Here, #2 means that the second expression in our SELECT list is causing the problem. In our case, it’s the Name column. We included the Name column in our SELECT list but not the GROUP BY clause.

Solution 1
Another way to deal with this issue is to include the Name column in the GROUP BY clause:

SELECT
District,
Name,
SUM(Population) FROM City
WHERE CountryCode = 'AUS'
GROUP BY District, Name;

Result:

+-----------------+---------------+-----------------+
| District        | Name          | SUM(Population) |
+-----------------+---------------+-----------------+
| New South Wales | Sydney        |         3276207 |
| Victoria        | Melbourne     |         2865329 |
| Queensland      | Brisbane      |         1291117 |
| West Australia  | Perth         |         1096829 |
| South Australia | Adelaide      |          978100 |
| Capital Region  | Canberra      |          322723 |
| Queensland      | Gold Coast    |          311932 |
| New South Wales | Newcastle     |          270324 |
| New South Wales | Central Coast |          227657 |
| New South Wales | Wollongong    |          219761 |
| Tasmania        | Hobart        |          126118 |
| Victoria        | Geelong       |          125382 |
| Queensland      | Townsville    |          109914 |
| Queensland      | Cairns        |           92273 |

Solution 2
Another way to deal with this error is with the ANY_VALUE() function.

SELECT
District,
ANY_VALUE(Name),
SUM(Population) FROM City
WHERE CountryCode = 'AUS'
GROUP BY District;
Result:

+-----------------+-----------------+-----------------+
| District        | ANY_VALUE(Name) | SUM(Population) |
+-----------------+-----------------+-----------------+
| New South Wales | Sydney          |         3993949 |
| Victoria        | Melbourne       |         2990711 |
| Queensland      | Brisbane        |         1805236 |
| West Australia  | Perth           |         1096829 |
| South Australia | Adelaide        |          978100 |
| Capital Region  | Canberra        |          322723 |
| Tasmania        | Hobart          |          126118 |
+-----------------+-----------------+-----------------+
The ANY_VALUE() function picks an arbitrary value from the specified column. In this case, it picked an arbitrary value from the Name column, and we got Sydney in the first row, Melbourne in the second, and so on. As we can see from the previous example, that column contains more than just those values for their respective districts, but MySQL has simply chosen one value to present.

Solution 3
Another option is to use the GROUP_CONCAT() function:

SELECT
District,
GROUP_CONCAT(Name),
SUM(Population) FROM City
WHERE CountryCode = 'AUS'
GROUP BY District;

Solution 4
We only get the error when our sql_mode contains ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY.

We can check our sql_mode like this:

SELECT @@sql_mode;
Result:

ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY,STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION
As expected, ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY is enabled, which is why I got the error.

We can disable ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY from our session’s sql_mode like this:

SET @@sql_mode = SYS.LIST_DROP(@@sql_mode, 'ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY');
SELECT @@sql_mode;
Result:

STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION
By using the SYS.LIST_DROP system function, we removed the item from the list without affecting any other items. We can see that ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY is no longer in our sql_mode.

Let’s now run the original query that caused the error:

SELECT
District,
Name,
SUM(Population) FROM City
WHERE CountryCode = 'AUS'
GROUP BY District;
Result:

+-----------------+-----------+-----------------+
| District        | Name      | SUM(Population) |
+-----------------+-----------+-----------------+
| New South Wales | Sydney    |         3993949 |
| Victoria        | Melbourne |         2990711 |
| Queensland      | Brisbane  |         1805236 |
| West Australia  | Perth     |         1096829 |
| South Australia | Adelaide  |          978100 |
| Capital Region  | Canberra  |          322723 |
| Tasmania        | Hobart    |          126118 |
+-----------------+-----------+-----------------+

Answer (score -1):

You can set the variables in mysql:

```
mysql> set global sql_mode='STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION';
mysql> set session sql_mode='STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION';
```

Remember NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER will not work with mysql 8.

If that doesn't work just do:

```
mysql > set sql_mode = ''
```