# MySQL Select only one row from each patient diagnosed according the first date

Tags: mysql, sql

**EDIT**

I cannot `group by` only with `patient_id`, I will get an error of `sql_mode=only_full_group_by...`

I have the following query which is helping me to get the list of all patient that has been diagnosed with diabetes:

```
SELECT t1.patient_id,
CONVERT(aes_decrypt(t4.patient_name_en, 'key1') USING utf8mb4) as patient_name_en,
t3.date_of_visit as date_of_visit, 
t2.diagnosis_name,
max(ifnull(t5.date_of_assessment, 'N/A')) as date_of_assessment,
ifnull(t5.assessment_result, 0) as assessment_result 
FROM consultation t1
LEFT JOIN diagnosis t2 ON t1.diagnosis_id = t2.diagnosis_id
LEFT JOIN visit t3 ON t3.visit_id = t1.visit_id
LEFT JOIN patient t4 ON t4.patient_id = t3.patient_id
LEFT JOIN diabetes_assessment t5 ON t5.patient_id = t4.patient_id
WHERE t2.diagnosis_name LIKE '%Diabetes%' AND t1.clinic_id = '361'
AND t3.visit_status="Active"
GROUP BY t1.patient_id, t5.date_of_assessment, t4.patient_name_en, t3.date_of_visit, t2.diagnosis_name, t5.assessment_result
ORDER BY t5.date_of_assessment DESC
```

The result is:

[image]

As you see if a patient is diagnosed multiple times with different types or level of diabetes, the rows are all shown. But what I really want is the first time he get diagnosed with it, so the result would be only these 2 rows highlighted in blue:

[image]

Here the patient 0361 first diagnised with diabetes in `2017-04-06`. So we get only this row for this patient.

I tried to use `min(t3.date_of_visit) but it didn't worked properly.

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 1):

I think what you want is the first visit and last diabetes_assessment. I have assumed that the first field in all your tables is an auto_increment field and that consultation_id in the fiddle is incorrectly typed.

Given the above

```
MariaDB [sandbox]> select p.patient_name_en,v.*,c.diagnosis_id,d.diagnosis_name,da.date_of_assessment,da.assessment_result
    -> from visit v
    -> join patient p on p.patient_id = v.patient_id
    -> join consultation c on c.patient_id = v.patient_id and c.visit_id = v.visit_id
    -> join diagnosis d on d.diagnosis_id = c.diagnosis_id
    -> left join
    -> (
    -> select da.patient_id, da.date_of_assessment,da.assessment_result
    -> from diabetes_assessment da
    -> where da.diabetes_assessment_id  = (select max(da1.diabetes_assessment_id) from diabetes_assessment da1 where da1.patient_id = da.patient_id)
    -> ) da on da.patient_id = v.patient_id
    -> where v.visit_id = (select min(visit_id) from consultation c where c.patient_id = v.patient_id)
    -> and c.diagnosis_id in (1,2)
    -> and v.clinic_id = 361
    -> ;
+-----------------+----------+------------+-----------+---------------+--------------+--------------+---------------------------------------------+--------------------+-------------------+
| patient_name_en | visit_id | patient_id | clinic_id | date_of_visit | visit_status | diagnosis_id | diagnosis_name                              | date_of_assessment | assessment_result |
+-----------------+----------+------------+-----------+---------------+--------------+--------------+---------------------------------------------+--------------------+-------------------+
| ABC             |        1 | 361-9001   |       361 | 2017-03-03    | Active       |            1 | Diabetes mellitus with diabetic nephropathy | 2017-05-05         |             40.00 |
| XYZ             |        3 | 361-0361   |       361 | 2017-10-03    | Active       |            2 | E01 Diabetes mellitus with kidney disease   | 2017-03-10         |             30.50 |
+-----------------+----------+------------+-----------+---------------+--------------+--------------+---------------------------------------------+--------------------+-------------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: it works. But I cannot add this line `and c.diagnosis_id in (1,2)` because there is multiple types of diabetes with different IDs.

Comment: Fair enough, I was being a bit lazy, try substituting your like condition.

Comment: In which select? The sub ?

Comment: and c.diagnosis_id in (1,2) >> and d.diagnosis_name LIKE '%Diabetes%'

Answer (score 0):

Just keep the **group by** clause `t1.patient_id, t5.date_of_assessment`.

So I read [this doc](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html)
if you don't require order by order by assisment date remove it, or keep the same in group by also.

Comment: if you need 1 row per patient, just group by Patient id.

Comment: I did it and now I got `Error Code: 1055. Expression #4 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'ncd.t2.diagnosis_name' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by`

Comment: I need to group by all fields and as I read somewhere we cannot change the sql mode of group by to null

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36207042/error-code-1055-incompatible-with-sql-mode-only-full-group-by   see this

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150399/discussion-between-shuddh-and-droidnation).

Answer (score 0):

**Solution 1:**
Change database to something using [Window Functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/tutorial-window.html), as apparently MySQL has big drawbacks on this field ([for example](http://veekaybee.github.io/mysql-window-functions/)). This could save your day

**Solution 2:** As probably the first solution won't be acceptable for you, you may try to use something like

```
    select t1.patient_id, min(t3.date_of_visit) "date_of_visit" 
    from consultation t1 
    LEFT JOIN visit t3 ON t3.visit_id = t1.visit_id
    group by t1.patient_id
```

You could join this as subquery or put it into some table (maybe even temporary). Join should be done by `patient` and `date_of_visit` then.

Unfortunatelly until you provide MCVE like Strawberry requests to, it will be hard to help more.