# Using sub query to group by specific column is outputting the same erroneous result

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery

I asked [this question few days ago](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45372199/mysql-select-only-one-row-from-each-patient-diagnosed-according-the-the-first-da/45372533?noredirect=1) on SO, but with no valid answer for it.

The problem was that the following query:

```
SELECT t1.patient_id,
CONVERT(aes_decrypt(t4.patient_name_en, :encKey) USING utf8mb4) as patient_name_en,
min(t3.date_of_visit) as date_of_visit, 
t2.diagnosis_name,
max(ifnull(t5.date_of_assessment, 'N/A')) as date_of_assessment,
ifnull(t5.assessment_result, 0) as assessment_result 
FROM consultation t1
LEFT JOIN diagnosis t2 ON t1.diagnosis_id = t2.diagnosis_id
LEFT JOIN visit t3 ON t3.visit_id = t1.visit_id
LEFT JOIN patient t4 ON t4.patient_id = t3.patient_id
LEFT JOIN diabetes_assessment t5 ON t5.patient_id = t4.patient_id
WHERE t2.diagnosis_name LIKE :diagName AND t1.clinic_id = :cid
AND t3.visit_status=:visit_status
GROUP BY t1.patient_id, t5.date_of_assessment, t4.patient_name_en, t3.date_of_visit, t2.diagnosis_name, t5.assessment_result
ORDER BY t5.date_of_assessment DESC
```

Is giving the following result:

[image]

But what I really want is to group by only `patient_id` so I can get only one row per one patient who was diagnosed earlier with Diabetes.

I searched a lot and found that I can use sub query inside this query.

So I came up with the following sub query:

```
SELECT t1.patient_id
FROM consultation t1
LEFT JOIN diagnosis t2 ON t1.diagnosis_id = t2.diagnosis_id
LEFT JOIN visit t3 ON t3.visit_id = t1.visit_id
LEFT JOIN patient t4 ON t4.patient_id = t3.patient_id
LEFT JOIN diabetes_assessment t5 ON t5.patient_id = t4.patient_id
WHERE t2.diagnosis_name LIKE '%Diabetes%' AND t1.clinic_id = '361'
AND t3.visit_status="Active"
GROUP BY t1.patient_id
```

The result was grouped by `patient_id`, and I got the 2 id that really want and not more. Even the patient with ID `0361` was diagnosed with multiple types of diabetes in each visit to the clinic, but it's id is shown once.

Now I want to take this sub query and add it to the initial one:

```
SELECT t1.patient_id,
CONVERT(aes_decrypt(t4.patient_name_en, 'key1') USING utf8mb4) as patient_name_en,
min(t3.date_of_visit) as date_of_visit, 
t2.diagnosis_name,
max(ifnull(t5.date_of_assessment, 'N/A')) as date_of_assessment,
ifnull(t5.assessment_result, 0) as assessment_result 
FROM consultation t1
LEFT JOIN diagnosis t2 ON t1.diagnosis_id = t2.diagnosis_id
LEFT JOIN visit t3 ON t3.visit_id = t1.visit_id
LEFT JOIN patient t4 ON t4.patient_id = t3.patient_id
LEFT JOIN diabetes_assessment t5 ON t5.patient_id = t4.patient_id
WHERE t1.patient_id IN 
(SELECT t1.patient_id
FROM consultation t1
LEFT JOIN diagnosis t2 ON t1.diagnosis_id = t2.diagnosis_id
LEFT JOIN visit t3 ON t3.visit_id = t1.visit_id
LEFT JOIN patient t4 ON t4.patient_id = t3.patient_id
LEFT JOIN diabetes_assessment t5 ON t5.patient_id = t4.patient_id
WHERE t2.diagnosis_name LIKE '%Diabetes%' AND t1.clinic_id = '361'
AND t3.visit_status="Active"
GROUP BY t1.patient_id) AND
t2.diagnosis_name LIKE '%Diabetes%' AND t1.clinic_id = '361'
AND t3.visit_status="Active"
GROUP BY t1.patient_id, t5.date_of_assessment, t4.patient_name_en, t3.date_of_visit, t2.diagnosis_name, t5.assessment_result
ORDER BY t5.date_of_assessment DESC
```

But I've got the same result of the image above, where per example `patient_id=0361` is shown in 4 rows, but I want is to be shown once, with the date of the first time he was diagnoised with Diabetes.

Comment: The query looks like it's in a mess and without seeing data I'm not suprised that you got no answer previously. Maybe if you can boil down your question to something simpler, perhaps a join involving only 2-3 tables, it might be easier to get help here.

Comment: Perhaps if you'd heeded the valuable advice afforded in comments

Comment: Guys I dont know how to create sql fiddles. Plus I have 6 tables. Will take an hour to create a fiddle right ?

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT t.patient_id,
CONVERT(aes_decrypt(t4.patient_name_en, 'key1') USING utf8mb4) as patient_name_en,
mindate as date_of_visit, 
tt2.diagnosis_name,
max(ifnull(tt5.date_of_assessment, 'N/A')) as date_of_assessment,
ifnull(tt5.assessment_result, 0) as assessment_result 
FROM consultation t
LEFT JOIN visit tt3 ON tt3.visit_id = t.visit_id
LEFT JOIN diagnosis tt2 ON t1.diagnosis_id = tt2.diagnosis_id
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT t1.patient_id,min(t3.date_of_visit) mindate
    FROM consultation t1
    LEFT JOIN diagnosis t2 ON t1.diagnosis_id = t2.diagnosis_id
    LEFT JOIN visit t3 ON t3.visit_id = t1.visit_id 
    WHERE t2.diagnosis_name LIKE '%Diabetes%' AND t1.clinic_id = '361'
    AND t3.visit_status="Active"
    GROUP BY t1.patient_id
)INNERTABLE ON t.patient_id=INNERTABLE.patient_id and INNERTABLE.mindate
LEFT JOIN patient t4 ON t4.patient_id = tt3.patient_id
LEFT JOIN diabetes_assessment t5 ON t5.patient_id = t4.patient_id
```

Try above query.

Comment: I will try it and get back to you.

Answer (score 0):

What is your final goal ?

Getting only patient_id, date_of_assessment ?  then you need only "group by" 1 column. like :

```
select patient_id, min(date_of_assessment) from .... where ....  group by patient_id
```

If you need to list diagnosis on the same column, you will need to use specific mysql thing, like :

```
select patient_id, min(date_of_assessment), GROUP_CONCAT(diagnosis SEPARATOR ' ') from .... where ... group by patient_id
```

Things is you need to give the database a way to compute a value for column you are not grouping by. It can be sum, count, min, max, ....