# How to preserve extra column after aggregation?

Tags: mysql, group-by, aggregate-functions, greatest-n-per-group

I have the following table in mysql which is a reduced version of a real problem.

```
+-------+-------+-------+-------+
| a_col | b_col | c_col | extra |
+-------+-------+-------+-------+
|     1 |     1 |     1 |     7 |*
|     1 |     2 |     1 |    10 |
|     1 |     2 |     2 |    20 |*
|     1 |     3 |     2 |    20 |
|     1 |     3 |     3 |    15 |*
+-------+-------+-------+-------+
```

I want to select the rows marked with *, to get the following table:

```
+-------+-------+-------+-------+
| a_col | b_col | c_col | extra |
+-------+-------+-------+-------+
|     1 |     1 |     1 |     7 |
|     1 |     2 |     2 |    20 |
|     1 |     3 |     3 |    15 |
+-------+-------+-------+-------+
```

If two rows have the same value in a_col AND b_col, then keep the one who has the greatest value in the c_col

My attempt was:

```
select a_col, b_col, max(c_col), extra
from mytable
group by a_col, b_col
```

But i get the following error message:

```
ERROR 1055 (42000): Expression #4 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'bd17_g12.mytable.extra' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by
```

without mentioning the "extra" column i get something close to what i desire:

```
+-------+-------+------------+
| a_col | b_col | max(c_col) |
+-------+-------+------------+
|     1 |     1 |          1 |
|     1 |     2 |          2 |
|     1 |     3 |          3 |
+-------+-------+------------+
```

But i need to keep the values of "extra" column

Answer (score 0):

You can get the `extra` and `c_col` column by applying aggregate `group_concat` function. And to pick the related highest c_col and its related extra value you can use `substring_index` over it

```
select a_col, b_col, max(c_col), 
substring_index(group_concat(extra order by c_col desc),',',1) `extra`
from mytable
group by a_col, b_col
```

[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ec9ff/3)

Or with self join

```
select a.*
from mytable a
left join mytable b 
          on a.a_col = b.a_col 
          and a.b_col = b.b_col
          and a.c_col < b.c_col
where b.c_col is null
```

[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ec9ff/4)

Answer (score 0):

As I understand, you want the `extra` for the biggest `c_col`.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/081e05/4)

**MySQL 5.6 Schema Setup**:

**Query 1**:

```
select t2.*
from (
  select a_col, b_col, max(c_col) c_colm
  from t
  group by a_col, b_col
  ) t1
  INNER join t t2 
    on t1.a_col = t2.a_col
      and t1.b_col = t2.b_col
      and t1.c_colm = t2.c_col
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/081e05/4/0)**:

```
| a_col | b_col | c_col | extra |
|-------|-------|-------|-------|
|     1 |     1 |     1 |     7 |
|     1 |     2 |     2 |    20 |
|     1 |     3 |     3 |    15 |
```

Answer (score 0):

The error that you get when you include the `extra` column does not seem to occur for a low version of mysql  (such as version 5.5). So the problem could be with the issue of 'ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY`  for higher versions of mysql such as discussed here: [Error Code: 1055 incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36207042/error-code-1055-incompatible-with-sql-mode-only-full-group-by)