# SQL NOT GROUP BY

Tags: sql, syntax

Table columns:

```
ID | KEY_CODE | CONFIRMS | TYPE | ID_TX | AMOUNT | ADDR | TIMESTAMP
```

Response without my help:

```
'1', '38ajZshxdf', '6', 'i', 'jZshxdyAyzXucVYe', 
'0.00763766','3126ad1ec17eb114', '1541991745'
```

My query:

```
SELECT
    id AS id,
    CASE 
        WHEN confirms >= 3 THEN 1
        ELSE 0
    END AS status,
    address,
    monto
FROM
    txs
WHERE
    address IN ('38ajZshxdfrfEGfyAyzXucVY6YXRQSWaGe', 
                '18jkwUXwDYGXz9raoRdmGWjJFYQV3uu17Y',  
                '12p5H7QK6Jgtsy27pMNkdgTPjhtt6sN6bM')
GROUP BY 
    address, status
```

I need group rows by status (if confirm > 3 then 1 else 0), SQL query needs to return TOTAL amounts on 1 and 0 and specific addresses (ADDR).

Like this:

```
ADDR, HAVE(0.00000000), STATUS (1 | 0)
```

Comment: The error message is pretty clear. A GROUP BY must include every column that is not aggregated, so you can't use it the way you are with SELECT *, txs.id, and so forth. Find a good book or tutorial on SQL and read the section on aggregated columns and GROUP BY to learn basic syntax.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error Code: 1055 incompatible with sql\_mode=only\_full\_group\_by](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36207042/error-code-1055-incompatible-with-sql-mode-only-full-group-by)

Comment: @Bummi i did think, i'm fixing, give me few minutes... and tell u

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are really wrong.. The `snytax` is not make much sense..

```
SELECT
    *,
    txs.id AS id,
    CASE 
        WHEN txs.confirms >= 3 THEN 1
        ELSE 0
    END AS status,
    address,
    FORMAT(SUM(monto) ,8) AS balance,
    tx,
    fecha
FROM
    txs
WHERE
    txs.address IN ([SOME_LIST])

GROUP BY MIN(status)
ORDER BY status ASC
```

You are use `*` and you do Aggregate.. It's obviously Clear error.. Because All column you call must put in `Group by` and Your `Group by` with `Min()`.. It can produce error too..

> aggregate functions are not allowed in GROUP BY

So just take column what you need.

```
SELECT
    txs.id AS id,
    CASE 
        WHEN txs.confirms >= 3 THEN 1
        ELSE 0
    END AS status,
    address,
    FORMAT(SUM(monto) ,8) AS balance,
    tx,
    fecha
FROM
    txs
WHERE
    txs.address IN ([SOME_LIST])
GROUP BY 
    id, 
    (CASE 
        WHEN txs.confirms >= 3 THEN 1
        ELSE 0
    END), 
    address, tx, fecha
ORDER BY 
     (CASE 
        WHEN txs.confirms >= 3 THEN 1
        ELSE 0
      END) ASC
```

*EDIT*:

Because your `status` are condition column.. Put full expression instead..

```
CASE 
  WHEN txs.confirms >= 3 THEN 1
  ELSE 0
END AS status
```

This is your `Status` column.. Because this are condition column.. You cannot group by in same level.. So put your full expression in `group by` condition. And as you can see.. I put that expression in `Group By` and `Order By` full expression of your `status` column condition..

```
GROUP BY 
    id, 
    (CASE 
        WHEN txs.confirms >= 3 THEN 1
        ELSE 0
    END), -----> This are Status Condition
    address, tx, fecha
ORDER BY 
     (CASE 
        WHEN txs.confirms >= 3 THEN 1
        ELSE 0 
      END) ASC -----------> and this too..
```

Comment: Need group BY status and address

Comment: If you're going to post an answer, at least make the code in it correct. You missed columns in the GROUP BY, just like the poster did, and your suggested code will generate the same error.

Comment: I edited, check again pls, my english is not very well, but i try.

Comment: Do you already try run my query? Just change `some list` with your data ..

Comment: No, but your code Group BY id and another fields, need group by address and status... because return many results.

Comment: Thanks is perfect, i fixed with SET SQL_MODE='';