# mysql making a group by function compliant with only_full_group_by

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, pivot, aggregate-functions

I have found a lot on here about only_full_group_by and it being in strict mode when you receive #1055 errors. The solutions I have found all involve disabling strict mode which users warn can cause other issues. My question is about making the query compliant instead of a work around. Can someone tell me if the query below can be made complaint while in strict mode and if so, what would change?

THE ERROR -  #1055 - expression #2 of select list is not in group by clause and contains nonaggregated column xxx which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incomptiable with sql_mode=only_full_group_by

```
 SELECT 
            post_id,
            name,
            Email,
            CustomerId,
            DeliveryDate,
            DeliveryTime,
            DeliveryType,
            Zip,
            OrderNote,
            PaymentTotal,
            OrderStatus
    
        FROM
            (SELECT 
                post_id,
                    name,
                    MAX((CASE WHEN (meta_key = '_rpress_payment_user_email') THEN meta_value END)) AS `Email`,
                    MAX((CASE WHEN (meta_key = '_rpress_payment_customer_id') THEN meta_value END)) AS `CustomerId`,
                    MAX((CASE WHEN (meta_key = '_rpress_delivery_date') THEN meta_value END)) AS `DeliveryDate`,
                    MAX((CASE WHEN (meta_key = '_rpress_delivery_time') THEN meta_value END)) AS `DeliveryTime`,
                    MAX((CASE WHEN (meta_key = '_rpress_delivery_type') THEN meta_value END)) AS `DeliveryType`,
                    MAX((CASE WHEN (meta_key = '_rpress_delivery_zip') THEN meta_value END)) AS `Zip`,
                    MAX((CASE WHEN (meta_key = '_rpress_order_note') THEN meta_value END)) AS `OrderNote`,
                    MAX((CASE WHEN (meta_key = '_rpress_payment_total') THEN meta_value END)) AS `PaymentTotal`,
                    MAX((CASE WHEN (meta_key = '_order_status') THEN meta_value END)) AS `OrderStatus`
            FROM
                (`wp_postmeta` `t1`
            JOIN `wp_rpress_customers` `t2` ON ((0 <> FIND_IN_SET(`t1`.`post_id`, `t2`.`payment_ids`))))
            GROUP BY `t1`.`post_id` , `t2`.`name`) `derived_table`
```

Comment: This looks like a valid aggregation query. Which error do you get exactly when running this under `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY`?

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36207042/error-code-1055-incompatible-with-sql-mode-only-full-group-by answer your question??

Comment: Consider handling issues of data display in application code

Comment: @strawberry, I am not sure what that means

Comment: @gmb I get a : 1055 - expression #2 of select list is not in group by clause and contains nonaggregated column xxx which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incomptiable with sql_mode=only_full_group_by

Comment: It's unusual to want to return a pivot to a MySQL command line interface. Usually, there's some kind of presentation layer (like PHP), which is where you could handle the formatting of data.

Comment: @yunfeichen thanks but no since that involves altering MYSQL operating and I am trying to avoid that. Others including on that stackoverflow question indicated taking it out of strict mode can cause other unintended issues down the line. I would prefer to alter my query to comply with the strict mode

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code looks like a valid aggregation query. It can, however, be vastly simplified: most parentheses around predicates are just not needed, and nesting the aggregate query is unnecessary. I would also recommend using meaningful table aliases, and prefixing all columns in the query with the (alias of the) table they belong to.

So:

```
SELECT 
    pm.post_id,
    c.name,
    MAX(CASE WHEN pm.meta_key = '_rpress_payment_user_email'  THEN pm.meta_value END) AS Email,
    MAX(CASE WHEN pm.meta_key = '_rpress_payment_customer_id' THEN pm.meta_value END) AS CustomerId,
    MAX(CASE WHEN pm.meta_key = '_rpress_delivery_date'       THEN pm.meta_value END) AS DeliveryDate,
    MAX(CASE WHEN pm.meta_key = '_rpress_delivery_time'       THEN pm.meta_value END) AS DeliveryTime,
    MAX(CASE WHEN pm.meta_key = '_rpress_delivery_type'       THEN pm.meta_value END) AS DeliveryType,
    MAX(CASE WHEN pm.meta_key = '_rpress_delivery_zip'        THEN pm.meta_value END) AS Zip,
    MAX(CASE WHEN pm.meta_key = '_rpress_order_note'          THEN pm.meta_value END) AS OrderNote,
    MAX(CASE WHEN pm.meta_key = '_rpress_payment_total'       THEN pm.meta_value END) AS PaymentTotal,
    MAX(CASE WHEN pm.meta_key = '_order_status'               THEN pm.meta_value END) AS OrderStatus
FROM wp_postmeta pm
INNER JOIN wp_rpress_customers c ON FIND_IN_SET(pm.post_id, c.payment_ids)
GROUP BY pm.post_id, c.name
```

I also removed the backticks around the identifiers, which do not seem very helpful (you can revert that change if you want otherwise).

Comment: thanks much. In putting this in I discovered that upon upgrading from MYSQL 5.7 to V8, apparently in some views that have a GROUP BY clause in them you have to DROP them and create them again? I used the above simplification for a less complex query and thank you for that.