# How to write subquery with same table in Laravel Eloquent?

Tags: sql, laravel, eloquent

How can I translate this SQL to Eloquent?

```sql
SELECT *
FROM actions A1
WHERE A1.recurring_pattern IS NOT NULL AND
    A1.parent_id IS NOT NULL AND
    A1.due_date = (
        SELECT MIN(due_date)
        FROM actions A2
        WHERE A2.parent_id = A1.parent_id AND 
            due_date > NOW()
    )
```

Answer (score 1):

If I'm not mistaken, what you want to do is to get one action per sibling of actions, which satisfies the conditions:

- the action must not be past due, but should be due next,
- the action must have a recurring pattern, and
- (of course) the action must have a parent.

If that's the case, your query can be simplified to:

```sql
SELECT * FROM actions
WHERE recurring_pattern IS NOT NULL
    AND parent_id IS NOT NULL
    AND due_date > NOW()
GROUP BY parent_id
HAVING MIN(due_date)
```

Basically you `SELECT` actions that satisfy the outlined conditions above, then `GROUP` them `BY` their parents, and finally pick one action per group `HAVING` the closest due date. This approach to querying eliminates the need to subquery.

Now, onto implementing the simplified query in Laravel Eloquent, we can define an `Action` model as follows:

```php
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Support\Carbon;

class Action extends Model
{
    /**
     * Scope to actions that have recurring pattern.
     */
    function scopeHasRecurringPattern(Builder $query)
    {
        $query->where('recurring_pattern', '<>', null);
    }

    /**
     * Scope to actions that have parents.
     */
    function scopeHasParent(Builder $query)
    {
        $query->where('parent_id', '<>', null);
    }

    /**
     * Scope to actions not due by the given date.
     */
    function scopeIsNotDueBy(Builder $query, Carbon $now)
    {
        $query->where('due_date', '>', $now);
    }
}
```

Then finally, we perform the query by doing:

```php
Action::hasRecurringPattern()    //  filter actions having recurring patterns
    ->hasParent()                //  filter actions having parents
    ->isNotDueBy(now())          //  filter actions not past due
    ->groupBy('parent_id')       //  group these filtered actions by identical parents
    ->havingRaw('MIN(due_date)') //  finally pick the action per group having the closest due date
    ->get();
```

Comment: Thank you so much! You understood perfectly my issue and provided a great answer!

Comment: However, I have the following error when I execute the code you suggested

Comment: : SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1055 Expression #1 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'tenant_company_develop.actions.id' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by (SQL: select * from `actions` where `recurring_pattern` is not null and `parent_id` is not null and `due_date` >= 2022-06-23 and `actions`.`deleted_at` is null group by `parent_id` having MIN(due_date))

Comment: That's unexpected. That happens when your MySQL database has `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` mode enabled.

See: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html#:~:text=If%20the%20ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY%20SQL%20mode,are%20functionally%20dependent%20on%20them.

Comment: In any case, helping you on that issue is an answer to a different question. However, a quick solution is to disable `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` mode. See answers on this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36207042/error-code-1055-incompatible-with-sql-mode-only-full-group-by/36207611#36207611:~:text=To%20remove%20the%20clause%20ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY%20you%20can%20do%20this

Comment: I hope my answer to your main question still gets accepted. :)